# Tips to practice matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-science

I've been studying python for data science for about 5 months now. But I get really stucked when it comes to matplotlib. There's always so many options to do anything, and I can't see a well defined path to do anything. Does anyone have this problem too and knows how to deal with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem sometime back. I just picked the Boston Housing Prices dataset and kept practicing on that. If you work on it enough you will be able to create all types of plots for the EDA and get good practice. Of course after a certain point it can get boring , thats when you jump to a dataset in an area of your interests, in my case it was movie reviews.

Below is the link to the housing prices data.
https://www.kaggle.com/c/house-prices-advanced-regression-techniques

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is stating that you are bored and do not have any projects to make. If that is correct, there are many datasets available on sites like Kaggle that have open-source datasets for practice programmers.

Comment: Yes, I think that's the point. I need a project. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

in programming in general " There's always so many options to do anything".
i recommend to you that read library and understand their functions and classes in a glance, then go and solve some problems from websites or give a real project if you can. if your code works do not worry and go ahead. 
after these try and error you have a lot of real idea about various problems and you recognize difference between these options and pros and cons of them. like me three years ago.